# Question on conservation of momentum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision

> 36. Consider the head-on collision between a lady bug and the windshield of a high speed bus. Which of the following statements are true? List all that apply.
>
> (a) The magnitude of the force encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus.
> (b) The magnitude of the impulse encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus.
> (c) The magnitude of the momentum change encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus.
> (d) The magnitude of the velocity change encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus.
> (e) The magnitude of the acceleration encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus.

In this question, why is (c) incorrect? The answer key says that the bug doesn't undergo any momentum change but because it's mass is constant and it certainly undergoes a velocity change doesn't the necessarily mean there is a change in momentum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The magnitude of the momentum change encountered by the bug is greater than that of the bus."

This is false.

Newtons third law: $F_{1}$=-$F_{2}$

They each experience equal and opposite forces. Change in momentum in its simplest form atleast, is F*t, they are experiencing the same magnitude of force, for the same time. Hence the same magnitude of change in momentum. The bugs acceleration however, is obviously larger because the mass is smaller.

Your answer key is wrong if it says the bug doesn't undergo any momentum change. That is extremely false

Answer (score 0):

According to Newton's Third law both the car and the bug experience the same forces in different directions, as you know :

$$F=dp/dt$$

So as both objects experience same force for same time the change in momentum *$\Delta P$*,  $c$ is incorrect.